# Meaning of these code line?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am a new learner and work on a quiz app ref. by the online tutorial.

I have a code of quiz app by the online tutorial. but some code line I do not understand.

I mean, I do not understand these line meaning and deceleration. please, anyone explain it. if your need original tutorial please see this 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3mTlr1Nlnc0&list=PLw5h0DiJ-9PBcL0sqrGXvSOYFncEAPObY&index=19

```
(function(){
var app = angular.module('myQuiz', []);
app.controller('QuizController', ['$scope', '$http', '$window', function($scope,$http, $window){
    $scope.quizSecHeight = $window.innerHeight;
    $scope.score = 0 ;
    $scope.activeQuestion = -1 ;
    $scope.activeQuestionAnswered = 0 ;
    $scope.percentage = 0 ;
    $http.get('quiz_data.html').then(function(quizData){
        $scope.myQuestions =  quizData.data;
        $scope.totalQuestions = $scope.myQuestions.length;
    });
    $scope.selectAnswer = function (qIndex, aIndex){
        var questionState = $scope.myQuestions[qIndex].questionState;
        $scope.myQuestions[qIndex].correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
        if ( questionState != 'answered' ){

            $scope.myQuestions[qIndex].selectedAnswer = aIndex;
            var correctAnswer =  $scope.myQuestions[qIndex].correct; // with isSelected
            $scope.myQuestions[qIndex].correctAnswer = correctAnswer; // with isCorrect

            if ( aIndex === correctAnswer ){
                 $scope.myQuestions[qIndex].correctness = "correct";
                 $scope.score += 1;
            } else {
                $scope.myQuestions[qIndex].correctness = "incorrect";
            }
            $scope.myQuestions[qIndex].questionState = "answered";
        }
        $scope.percentage = ($scope.score / $scope.totalQuestions)*100; 
    }
    $scope.isSelected = function(qIndex, aIndex){
        return $scope.myQuestions[qIndex].selectedAnswer === aIndex;
    }
    $scope.isCorrect = function(qIndex, aIndex){
        return $scope.myQuestions[qIndex].correctAnswer === aIndex;
    }
    $scope.selectContinue = function(){
        return $scope.activeQuestion +=1;
    }
}]);
```

})();

on this code i am understand all lines but not understand

```
var questionState = $scope.myQuestions[qIndex].questionState;
$scope.myQuestions[qIndex].correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
if ( questionState != 'answered' ){
```

Comment: Simple javascript! :). If you can post more code like where it is being used, we can explain it much better

Comment: Ok i am update my full code and give a link of tutorial

Answer (score 0):

myQuestions is an scope array containing question State(may be State is for is it answered or not).

I guess, these line are from a function which is getting an argument 'qIndex'(and correctAnser).
May be this function called when user creating a question and telling which answer is correct.

Thats what I understand from your question.

Comment: i have update my question please check it again and update me.

Comment: explain what you dont understand, function calling , passing variable or anything else.

like in this line
$scope.myQuestions[qIndex].correctAnswer = correctAnswer
you are saving the answer in your array